# Why am I getting bad_alloc? Implementing a stack c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stack, bad-alloc

I'm trying to implement my own Stack in C++ but I keep getting this error when I try to use the method pop() in which what I'm trying to do is:

1. Save element from the top in a variable called "res".
2. Get the reference to the next element from the node class and set it as the top.
3. size--
4. Return the variable "res".

If you could help me I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Node class:

```
template<class T>
class Node {
private:
    Node<T>* next;
    T element;

public:
    Node();

    Node(const Node& orig);

    ~Node();

    void setElement(T el);

    T getElement();

    Node<T>* getNext();

    void setNext(Node<T>* ne);
};
```

Stack class:

```
#include "EmptyStackException.cpp"
#include "Node.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class LinkedStack {
private:
    int siz;
    Node<T>* first;

public:
    LinkedStack();

    ~LinkedStack();

    int size();

    bool isEmpty();

    void push(T e);

    T top();

    T pop();
};

template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::push(T e) {
    Node<T> node = Node<T>();
    node.setNext(first);
    node.setElement(e);
    first = &node;
    siz++;
}

template<class T>
T LinkedStack<T>::pop() {
    T res = first->getElement();
    first = *(first->getNext());
    siz--;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: The [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) says you will require an assignment operator for `Node` and `LinkedStack`, and `LinkedStack` will also need a copy constructor. In addition many of the existing constructors and destructors don't do what they should be doing.

Comment: You can't store the result of `&` for later use. You need dynamic allocation.

Comment: `first = &node;` takes a pointer to a local object, which ceases to exist when your function returns. You will need to use some form of dynamic allocation.

Comment: Amazing how often I see a question about a problem caused by storing pointers to local variables. Is this obviously-wrong pattern being taught somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::push(T e) {
    Node<T> node = Node<T>();
    node.setNext(first);
    node.setElement(e);
    first = &node;
    siz++;
}
```

Since `node` is an object that is local to this function, as soon as this function ends, it is destroyed. However, `first` contains a pointer to it. So when this function returns, `first` contains a pointer to an object that no longer exists. You probably want this:

```
template<class T>
void LinkedStack<T>::push(T e) {
    Node<T>* node = new Node<T>();
    node->setNext(first);
    node->setElement(e);
    first = node;
    siz++;
}
```

Now, `node` still ceases to exist when this function returns. But `first` doesn't contain a pointer to `node`, it contains the value of `node` -- a pointer to a dynamically allocated object.

Note that you will have to manage the lifetime of that object somehow. Ideally, you wouldn't use raw pointers so that you don't have that burden.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal No, it's not right. In both cases, `node` is a local object that is destroyed when the function terminates. But in the former case, `node` is that `Node` that you stored a pointer to. In the latter case, `node` is just a pointer that is no longer needed after the function terminates. If you create an object with `new`, it exists until you call `delete` on it.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal Your code may have other more subtle bugs in it, but you won't be able to find the subtle ones until you fix the obvious ones. Properly managing the lifetime of the objects in your collection is critical. Why not use `unique_ptr` or the like to ease your burden?

Comment: @DavidSchwarz Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is likely part of a classroom assignment where managing pointers with c++ 11 smart pointers may not be allowed. Outside of the classroom I entirely agree why bother to put yourself into the situation of manual  memory management if you don't specifically have to?